# Trigger a function at random time on every day with Quartz

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

how to trigger a function on every day at random time (0-24)
or fire once per day at given time range (9:00 am - 6:00 pm) with Quartz.

Such as, today it will work at 11:20 am, tomorrow 04:12 pm

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which is it? Between `00:00` & `00:00` or `09:00` & `18:00`?

Comment: Is it important? How can there be a change in both cases? In fact, I want to give begin and end time.

Comment: It's is a little bit trickier to get the logic right if it can be within a full 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing it like this:

1. Delete current trigger after execution
2. Create new trigger for the next day
3. Repeat

The code for creating the code could be something like this:

```
    public DailyTimeIntervalTriggerImpl GetNextTrigger(int minHour, int maxHour)
    {
        var random = new Random();

        int randomHour = random.Next(minHour, maxHour + 1);
        int randomMinute = random.Next(0, 60);

        var nextDayOfWeek = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek;
        var daysOfWeek = new Quartz.Collection.HashSet<System.DayOfWeek>() { nextDayOfWeek };

        var trigger = new DailyTimeIntervalTriggerImpl
        {
            DaysOfWeek = daysOfWeek,
            StartTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
            StartTimeOfDay = new TimeOfDay(randomHour, randomMinute, 0),
            TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc
        };
        return trigger;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't do `var random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);`. It's just as good to do `var random = new Random();`. Even better would be to make a field-level variable, and even better a thread-static field.

Comment: You also probably want to change the calls to `random.Next(...)` to be `random.Next(minHour, maxHour + 1)` and `random.Next(0, 60)` as the upper bound is ***exclusive***.

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity for your effort. But, trigger has no name, you did not define, why? Also, this code works only for next day. My actual problem trigger should be set today schedule and then your code, is it possible?

Comment: @HakanIlgar The name can be added in the construction of `DailyTimeIntervalTriggerImpl`, adding `Name = "my trigger name"` below `TimeZone` (for example). This code works indeed only for the next day... if you want to trigger it for today you will have other problems such as being already too late in the day so `minHour` and `maxHour` are "in the past". Keep in mind that with this code you have to recreate the trigger every single time the previous trigger has finished. IMO the challenge is not the first trigger, but removing and adding a new trigger every time.